# ASP.NET dynamic button creation with event handler

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a ASP.NET web form and I am generating a button dynamically. If the button is clicked, I want it redirected to a new page but it doesn't work. Here is what my Page_Load event and event handler look like

Below is a sample code snippet

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button editBtn = new Button();
    editBtn.Text = "Edit";
    editBtn.ID = i.ToString();
    editBtn.Command += MyBtnClick;

    TableRow row = new TableRow();
    TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

        cell1.Controls.Add(editBtn);
    row.Cells.Add(cell1);

    Table1.Rows.Add(row);

}

private void MyBtnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = (Button)sender;

    Response.BufferOutput = true;
    Response.Redirect(~/NextPage.aspx); 
}
```

Why is that the event handler is not fired?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To delegate button click to MyButton click use the following:

```
editBtn.Click += new EventHandler(MyBtnClick);
```

Comment: i tried inserting, but the MyBtnClick doesnt fire, when the button is clicked, it doesnt fire that function. Thanks